# How to convert user input to snake_case using Pydantic base model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic, snakecasing

I have a pydantic BaseModel which looks like:

```
class BookCreation(BaseModel):
    book_name: str
    book_size: Optional[str]
    book_author: str
```

Now, when the user passes the an input with inconsistent case as below:

```
{
    "book_name": "new-book",
    "book_SIZE": "23",
    "book_author": "test value"
}
```

Now this inputs is treated as if it has only two valid attributes i.e, `book_name` and `book_author` and `book_size` is assigned to `None`.

How do I ensure that the input changes to `snake_case` when I parse the input?

Comment: Do you expect any other form of input other than the one like `book_SIZE` (e.g. "booksize", "b00k_sIzE", etc.)? Also, do you use Pydantic combined with another framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can user alias generators for this. See the following example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict
from typing import Optional


def to_lower(string: str) -> str:
    return string.lower()

    
class BookCreation(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(alias_generator=to_lower)
    book_name: str
    book_size: Optional[str] = None
    book_author: str


data = {
    "book_name": "new-book",
    "book_SIZE": "23",
    "book_author": "test value"
}

print(BookCreation.model_validate(data))
```

Which prints:

```
book_name='new-book' book_size=None book_author='test value'
```

Depending on your use case you can adapt the `to_lower` function to handle whatever convention you might want to support.

I hope this helps!